# Where should I store a static list like states or cities in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to prevent going to the database if possible.  This is a rarely changing list of cities and states that will be populated in the beginning of the project and used by the application to format and find verify those locations.

So far from my research:

- config/initializers
- yml file
- database but cache it (I don't want to
  hit the database)

Kind of confused so want the best method for performance and convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest going one of two ways:

- create a ruby object by hand, which contains the data and can answer the relevant questions:

  ```
  class Cities
    def self.data
      {
        1: 'New York',
        2: 'Boston'
      }
    end

    def self.find_name_by_id(id)
      data[id]
    end
  end
  ```

  This means doing a bit more by hand and not having everything "free" that ActiveRecord normally gives you. Or...
- If you are certain that you need all the bells and whistles of ActiveRecord you can also use a gem for this: https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash. It does what you want and can store the data to an object in a hash or a yaml file. It will do associations and offers the object methods that one is used to from ActiveRecord.

Comment: Where would I put this object?  Would it be under app/models? Would it be better as a module in the lib folder?

Comment: That is a matter of taste. I generally dislike putting things in lib and would leave it in app/models.